# Prevent bootstrap 'hidden-print' inheritance (a.k.a. overwriting hidden-print)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a large HTML page with `hidden-print` class declared somewhere near the top, however it has a window (absolute-positioned) that needs to be printed.

**Question:** is it possible to force printing an element that is down the tree from `hidden-print` parent?

Applying hidden-print to individual elements is not an option since the HTML is generated dynamically and I have no control over the parent styling.

My html (simplified for clarity):

```
<div>
   <div class="hidden-print">
     <div>This should not be visible while printing</div>
     <div>This should not be visible either</div>
     <div class="do-print">This SHOULD be visible</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media print {
  .do-print {
    display:block !important;
    visibility:visible !important;
    opacity:1 !important;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
  }  
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0j4oeat/2/)

Comment: If a parent element is hidden via `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` the children of said element cannot be displayed.  If I understand what you are asking, then it is impossible to hide a parent but show the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **impossible** to do, due to Bootstrap using **[`display:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)** in order to hide the element from print. You can't have a child element that is displayed inside of an element that is not displayed.

**However**, the effect that you're attempting to achieve **is possible** if you create your own custom functionality to handle this. You can make use of **[`visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)** and **`visibility: visible`** instead, as an element can be made visible inside of an invisible parent.

The difference is in the way **`display:none`** works; it actually **removes** the element from the DOM:

> [...] the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all descendant elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.

If the parent element is removed, the child element is also removed. Conversely, **`visibility: hidden`** simply **hides** the element; it is still visible in the DOM:

> The visibility CSS property can show or hide an element without affecting the layout of a document (i.e., space is created for elements regardless of whether they are visible or not).

Thus, you can add styling to a child element in order to display it:

```css
@media print {
  .no-print {
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
  .do-print {
    visibility: visible !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="no-print">
    <div>This should not be visible while printing</div>
    <div>This should not be visible either</div>
    <div class="do-print">This SHOULD be visible</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also created a fiddle demonstrating this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/ssgooek4/)**.

Note that making use of **`visibility: hidden`** will position the element where it is **with the inclusion of the hidden content**. If you want to re-position the element to accommodate for the now invisible elements, you need to adjust the positioning inside the **`print`** media query.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: This is a good idea, except it leaves blank spaces where hidden content resides. I suppose I could create a SCSS rule for no-print that can apply `display:none` only to children that do not have `do-print` class

Comment: An interesting point. Yes, by default, the element would be wherever it appeared with the inclusion of the hidden content. If you want to move it up, I'd recommend adjusting the positioning of the visible element in the media query. I'll update my answer to cover that.